# Navbar doesn't direct to a URL

Tags: python, html, navbar

For starters, i have  basically no experience with coding, i followed a tutorial on how to code a website and when i tried to develope the idea for my own purposes i can't seem to get anywhere.

```
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="/">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="/logout">Logga ut</a>          
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="öppettider" href="/öppettider">Öppettider</a>
      {% else %}
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/login">Logga in</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="sign-Up" href="/sign-up">Registrera</a>
      {% endif %}
```

the navbar item "öppettider" is supposed to direct to a HTML in python where i intend to display a picture, atleast this is how i thought it would work. this resulted in 404 not found.
The other navbar items have their seperate .HTML files so i figured that navbar refers to .HTML's

Essentially i tried to expand a simple "post notes" website to be more of a "presentation" website.
By creating a new .HTML in templates and creating a navbar item for this .HTML.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, it seems that you are using `flask` or `django`.

When you go on a URL in `django` or `flask`, it does not point directly to `html` template. It first checks all the `urlpatterns` provided, which in the case of `flask` are written along with the `views`. A `view` is the functions which will be called if a certain URL is being called. That function decides what to do next. To render a `html` template, you'll have to return the template from that view, and ONLY then, your `html` template is rendered.

As you have said that you just created a new HTML file and a url in navbar, that will not just work. You'll have to create those views and urlpatterns for the program to know which template to go on, or more precisely what to do next after reaching that url.

###### Flask

If you are using `flask`, you must add your `view` for this particular URL

```
# A basic view example without any params
@app.route('/öppettider')
def öppettiderView():
    return render_template('öppettiderTemplate.html')
```

###### Django

If you are using `django`, you must change your views.py and urls.py accordingly

urls.py

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('öppettider/', views.öppettiderView, name='members'),
]
```

views.py

```
...
# A basic view example without any params
def öppettiderView(request):
    return render(request, 'öppettiderTemplate.html', context)
```